# Swift: Date parsing on daylight saving time

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

I have received date-time as String from server. I am unable to parse Date if date time is exact time of daylight saving time happen. How to handle when date-time string is `"2022-03-13T02:00:00.000000"`

**Output:**

```
2022-03-13 05:00:00 +0000
2022-03-13 06:59:00 +0000
failed
2022-03-13 07:00:00 +0000
2022-03-13 08:00:00 +0000
```

**Code:**

```
extension String {
    
    func date(using format: String) {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = format
        df.timeZone = .current
        if let date = df.date(from: self) {
            print(date)
        }
        else {
            print("failed")
        }
    }
}

"2022-03-13T00:00:00.000000".date(using: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
"2022-03-13T01:59:00.000000".date(using: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
"2022-03-13T02:00:00.000000".date(using: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
"2022-03-13T03:00:00.000000".date(using: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
"2022-03-13T04:00:00.000000".date(using: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
```

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: What result do you expect for a time that doesn’t exist? Is the input really given in the current time zone?

Comment: i am trying to find a way to handle this. right now, it is unable to parse the entire json. timezone - newyork

Comment: Just assume the string is derived from a date at GMT0 thus configure the date formatter with such time zone.

Comment: You need to set the time zone of the formatter to New York then.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Why assume that the string was derived from such time zone and not from GMT0?

Comment: Because op wrote New York. What is GMT0 btw, how is it different from GMT?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes GMT +0 same as GMT

Comment: @JoakimDanielson in the strings he’s trying to convert to date there is just the UTC shift, hence use the GMT+0 as time zone for converting them into a date. Then when he’s going to display the dates again he shall use a date formatter settled for the user’s desired time zone.

Comment: @valeCocoa there is no timezone information at the date strings posted by OP. Only fractional seconds. `"2022-03-13T02:00:00.000000"` can be current timezone or UTC. IMO it is probably UTC.

Comment: @LeoDabus because of that I’m assuming those are ISO8601 time stamps, hence that would be an UTC value. 
For example, I live in Italy and we adopt daylight savings, hence when it’s summertime a time stamp from our local time would have UTC+2, but our time zone is GMT+1.

Comment: @valeCocoa why it add 5 hour on time.

Comment: @Shohrab where is your date string coming from? Usually you would have the date string timezone info provided by your API. The most common usage is to send UTC time to the backend. Btw there is no 5 hour added to the time. If you want to know the time at your timezone you can use date.description(with: .current). Again check if the date string timezone is UTC with your api documentation and change your date formatter method from current to UTC in case it is UTC

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for explanation. will follow up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set your date formatter's calendar property. This will also avoid using the user device's calendar which might result in parsing the wrong year. Don't forget to always set your date formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" when parsing a fixed date format:

```
extension String {
    func date(using format: String) -> Date? {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)
        df.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        df.timeZone = .current
        df.dateFormat = format
        df.date(from: self) 
    }
}
```

Note also that this approach will create a new date formatter every time you call this method. You should avoid that as well creating a static formatter. I would also make sure if the date string is using the current timezone. Usually it is UTC timezone.

Comment: thanks. just to understand what following like do - df.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)

Comment: The date formatter needs a calendar to know which is the next time available after the timezone daylight savings transition date. You can use Gregorian calendar as well.

Comment: @LeoDabus TimeZone also has informations for daylight savings, where UTC is just the hour shift from GMT+0.

Comment: timezone won't help here. I mean if using anything other than UTC which doesnt have DST.  In other words any timezone which has daylight savings transitions would have the same issues

Comment: You are the one talking about time zone in the time stamp inside your answer. The time stamp in the question perhaps was not copied rightly and lacks a final “Z” character, hence the time represented is at ZULU (GMT); this is why for decoding purposes (the time stamp is inside a JSON as stated in the question) I’ve recommended adopting a ISO8601DateFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

Adopt the `ISO8601DateFormatter` To convert those strings into dates, then when you need to display them into your app use a date formatter set to the desired time zone.

In this way you won’t have any trouble with daylight savings conversions.

Of course when you need to re-encode a date into a `String` For transmitting it use again the `ISO8601DateFormatter` In order to keep the same format used for receiving them.

Comment: You mean `ISO8601DateFormatter`. The question is tagged as Swift

Comment: Yes thanks, I’m editing my answer.

Comment: This one is actually legit as it takes into consideration all user's settings on device. With older DateFormatter with manual dateFormat we always missed one corner case. This one should be marked as true answer. There is no need to use old DateFormatter in iOS10+.